# Multiple store view with same code

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I am working on a  website in magento. Which has two store (base, boutique) and 4 store view 
base (fr,en) and boutique (bfr,ben).
Now when I am using store URL in site url. I am getting 4 urls for every store view

```
http://example.com/en
http://example.com/fr
http://example.com/boutique/ben
http://example.com/boutique/bfr
```

We want the url of other store as shown below :

```
http://example.com/boutique/en
http://example.com/boutique/fr
```

but we have already store view with these codes.
Please help how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same code for 2 store views. Period.
But you can try a different approach to have your url's like this.
Don't use 'Add store codes to url' and instead actually create the folders you need `fr`, `en`, `boutique/en`, `boutique/fr` and copy the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files to each one of those folders and replace the following.

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

with

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

or

```
$mageFilename = '../../app/Mage.php';
```

depending on the depth of the folders.

And replace this

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

with

```
Mage::run('store code here', 'store'); //instead of store code view put en, fr, ben or bfr
```

You also need to adjust the base urls for each store view from system->configuration.

Comment: Thanks Marius for letting me know about this approach

Comment: I used this approach and it works. But how  to manage media skin and css url in this.

Comment: @user2932242. You have 2 options for media and skin.  Either add a rule on the server that states .. "every request for every website that contains `media` or `skin` or `js` right after the base urls  should go to the `media` or `skin` or `js`".  Or you change the base urls for media skin and js to point to the base domain. You achieve this second one from `System->Configuration->Web->Usecure/Secure`. Play with the urls. But backup first.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second approach. Everything is working but not skin urls.

Comment: @user2932242. Your skin url should be `http://example.com/skin/` for all store views. Don't forget the `/` at the end. It's important.